# Cannot restart Google Cloud VM

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

I ended my trial period with google cloud, and I have upgraded my account, still my virtual machine is stopped and I get this following error, which I couldn't manage to solve.

Starting VM instance "hasoffer-api" failed. Error: The default network interface [nic0] is frozen.

Can anyone give me a tip to solve this issue?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Probably you'll need to open an issue at the Issue Tracker at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Solution was only possible contacting google support. They took a couple of days to de-froze the VM

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, that error is due to a deletion process of the project or a recently change in your billing account, what it seems to be your problem.

In this case, it is neccesary to file a case to Google Support.